# Functional analysis on a more generalized setting- reference request

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request

Does anyone know of any good reference discussing functional analysis on a more generalized setting than on normed spaces. I was wondering whether there is a good book on the subject of such analysis say over modules, which discuss norms on rings and so on.

Thanks in advance to the repliers.

Comment: There are books on topological vector spaces, and on normed algebras, especially Banach algebras. Rudin's *Functional Analysis* certainly treats these.

Comment: Are you familiar with literature for such analysis on modules?

Comment: Possibly [**Topological Uniform Structures**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486658082) by Warren Page would be of interest to you. It's pretty heavy-going with all sorts of abstract structures, primarily those based on uniform spaces.